# Changing BizForm properties Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, kentico

I am currently trying to have a bizform as part of my transformation as:

```
<cms:BizForm runat="server" ID="BizForm" FormName="YourBizFormCodeName" EnableViewState="false" FormDisplayText="Form submitted"/>
```

In the DocumentType/PageType I have a field that allows the user to enter whatever they want to display once the form has been submitted, so in theory I need to go about and change FormDisplayText to what has been provided.

I have tried using Eval("SubmitText") inside FormDisplayText, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works fine for me (Kentico v8.1):

```
<cms:BizForm runat="server" ID="BizForm" FormName="test" EnableViewState="false" 
FormDisplayText='<%# CMS.MacroEngine.MacroContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("{%CurrentDocument.SubmitText#%}") %>' />
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I am using Kentico 8.0. Could you please see if there is any other solution? Thank you

Comment: What does it say? It's possible that only a namespace or class name is incorrect... (CMS.MacroEngine.MacroContext)

Comment: For v8 it should be CMS.CMSHelper.CMSContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros()

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have tried this on FormDisplayName, and it works fine, however as addition I want to be able to change the FormName too in the same manner, and it doesn't work, no error messages are produced

Comment: `FormName='<%# CMS.MacroEngine.MacroContext.CurrentResolver.ResolveMacros("{%CurrentDocument.FormName#%}") %>'` works perfectly fine for me. Make sure you save the macro without trailing #. To be sure it gets re-signed.

Comment: It doesn't work on the current version of Kentico I am using 8.0

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work first but then I wrote the expression once again (not copy&paste) and it worked. There are some illegal characters in the "FormName" word. (Just tested it in v8 and it works fine.)